# Unity Firebase Storage - Check if file exists Async

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, asynchronous, firebase-storage

After some advise around calls to firebase storage primarily how (from a sync POV) I should be checking to see if a file exists.

To set the context I am reading in a state file as json using the DownloadCoroutine function below and passing this into a JsonTextReader, this is working fine as long as the file exists in the first place (which as a new user it will not).

So then I wrote the below checkIfFile exists function which also works in a standalone capacity (Grabs the URL to prove that this file does in fact exist). Once this function has completed I then set a bool (SaveFileExists) to say this is/is not an existing file then go create one dependent on the state.

Where my problem lies is the order in which these functions are executed, I need the check to happen before any other methods are executed, they are both called in the LoadScene function currently. What I think I need to do is make the check an Async method returning a task? If so how would this look and where should I be calling it from, I have tried this but I think it keeps locking the main thread.

So the state right now is that because that bool doesnt change in time, the download of the storage file doesnt happen and the Json is never read in and throws an error, at the end of the console output the checkfile URL is outputted, any help would be great ,thanks.

```
  private IEnumerator DownloadCoroutine(string path)
        {
            var storage = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance; 
            var storageReference = storage.GetReference(path);

            if (SaveFileExists == true)
             {
                var DownloadTask = storageReference.GetBytesAsync(long.MaxValue);
                yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => DownloadTask.IsCompleted); 
                byte[] fileContents = DownloadTask.Result;
                retrievedSaveFile = Encoding.Default.GetString(fileContents);
                Debug.Log("Downloading the save file"); 
             }
             else 
             {
                createNewSaveFile(path);

             }
         }
```

Check to see if the Json file exists

```
 private void CheckIfFileExists(string path)
        {
            var storage = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance; 
            var storageReference = storage.GetReference(path);
            storageReference.GetDownloadUrlAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
                if (!task.IsFaulted && !task.IsCanceled) {
                 Debug.Log("Download URL: " + task.Result);
                 SaveFileExists = true; 
                      }
                      else{
                         
                          Debug.Log("file doesnt exist so we create one"); 

                      }
              });
        }
```

Load scene

```
  public IEnumerator LoadLastScene()
    {
        var User = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser;
        Debug.Log("USERID IS " + User.UserId.ToString()); 
        CheckIfFileExists("Saves://" + User.UserId.ToString() + "saveFile.json");
        yield return DownloadCoroutine("Saves://" + User.UserId.ToString() + 
        "saveFile.json");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The things you have to do is that

- User authentication
- Everything must be inside an async task function
- check if the file exists

  ```
               await storageRef.Root.Child(fUser.UserId).Child("Data").GetDownloadUrlAsync().ContinueWith(async task2 =>
               {
                   if (task2.IsFaulted || task2.IsCanceled)
                   {
                       Debug.Log("<color=Red>File Not Exists</color>");
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       Debug.Log("<color=green>File Exists</color>");
                       await DownloadData();
                   }
               });
  ```

Comment: The user is authenticated and I am trying to check if the file exists as I Described, I need this check to happen against the specific URL that I am passing in to occur before I create a new file. Could you suggest any changes to the code I posted above? thanks.

Comment: ` await storageRef.Root.Child(fUser.UserId).Child("FileToCheckInTheStorage ").GetDownloadUrlAsync().ContinueWith(async task2 =>`  Normally, this is how you should check, from the root of the storage. Even if you dont have subfolder, you must have a root.

Comment: I dont want the check to happen every single time I need to download the updated state file, it should happen once then set this bool or else its going to generate alot of traffic to firebase for no reason. There must be another way to just wrap this check function in some async logic so it finishes first surely ?

Comment: yield return new WaitForSeconds(1); FYI ive added this in the download coroutine which has solved my problem, I should imagine this is far from best practice but itll serve for now.